# Colorizing grayscale image

Tags: javascript, image, html, svg, svg-filters

I'm trying to colorize grayscale images on the fly with user-selected foreground and background colors (limited to red, green, blue, cyan, magenta, yellow, black, and white). The effect I want is as follows:

[original grayscale http://crawdad.cornell.edu/test/1.png](http://crawdad.cornell.edu/test/1.png)
[red foreground http://crawdad.cornell.edu/test/2.png](http://crawdad.cornell.edu/test/2.png)
[red foreground, yellow background http://crawdad.cornell.edu/test/3.png](http://crawdad.cornell.edu/test/3.png)

From left to right, these show the original grayscale image, that image where the user selected red as background color, and the same image with red background/yellow foreground.

Redrawing the images in a canvas every time the user selects a color is not practical (images will be 800x800px and I need to create 30 frames for animation).

I am only targeting the most recent version of WebKit, Firefox, and Internet Explorer, so html5, css3, and svg effects are fine. Images can be straight html `<img>` tag or can be `<image>` within an `<svg>` tag (the latter is actually preferable).

An ideal solution might involve svg filters (which I have no experience with, can they do this?). Another possibility might treat my grayscale image as an alpha channel with a solid color above it and a solid color below it (not sure how I'd do that on the fly).

For those having experience with Adobe Director, the effect I want is the same as Director's color and bgColor properties. (I'm converting a project from Director to html5/javascript.)

Comment: Since your selection of colours is limited it might actually be simplest to have those 8 options as png files with transparent backgrounds. Then the background colour is just CSS and you're done. 30fps may be too much.

Comment: @popnoodles (thanks for editing in the images). I'll give that a try, though it may still involve an impractical number of images (I have many more shapes to deal with than the spiral shown here). I've also started looking into svg filters. The feComponentTransfer filter looks promising.

Comment: Oh, then I wouldn't even entertain what I said. From the info given I was under the impression there were 8 possible saved images. SVG makes most sense.

Comment: You can use http://codewelt.com/blendmode

Comment: The svg filter looks promising:
http://jsfiddle.net/yPXf5/
Unfortunately, I haven't yet found good documentation of the tableValues attribute. So far, I'm having to figure this out empirically. Will post again if I get some good info. (If anyone can point me to good info on the tableValues attribute, please do so!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I have a solution using SVG filters.

```
<defs>
    <filter id="colorize">
        <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
            <feFuncR id="fR" type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
            <feFuncG id="fG" type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
            <feFuncB id="fB" type="table" tableValues="0 1"/>
        </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
</defs>
<image  filter="url(#colorize)" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="urlOfGrayscaleImage"/>
```

and then use JavaScript to set the `tableValues` (to simplify that, I gave `feFuncR` et al `id`s) as follows. The first number in each `tableValues` is the value that should replace black in the image, the second number is the value that should replace white. Thus to change black/white to red/yellow, the `tableValues` for `feFuncR`, `feFuncG`, and `feFuncB` are "1 1", "0 1", and "0 0", respectively. (Map the rgb range of 0-255 to 0-1.)

Setting `color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"` is critical. I was going nuts trying to work this out yesterday before someone else pointed it out to me.

Note: As of 12/27/12, Safari ignores `color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"`, while Chrome and Firefox use it. I hope Safari releases a version using a more recent WebKit; this isn't the only lingering SVG bug in Safari that has long since been fixed in Chrome.

I hope this is useful to someone!

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the wonderful world of [SVG filter effects](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html), where anything's possible but it takes forever to figure it out. Below is an example of how to do what you want with red and blue. The blending might not be exactly what you're looking for, and you might benefit from adding some transparency to the color.

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" id="mk">
      <feImage xlink:href="http://crawdad.cornell.edu/test/1.png" result="img"/>
      <feBlend in="img" in2="SourceGraphic" mode="multiply"> </feBlend>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="red" filter="url(#mk)" />
  <rect x="110" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" filter="url(#mk)" />
</svg>
```

The [`feBlend`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feBlendElement) element has a few more modes that you can try. Also the [`feComposite`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feCompositeElement) and [`feColorMatrix`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feColorMatrixElement) elements might be of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks - that may be simpler that what I'm trying now with `feComponentTransfer` (http://jsfiddle.net/yPXf5/5/). I'm not sure how it could change, for example, black to yellow and white to red as in the above examples. I'll have to explore modes other than multiply.

Comment: @BobW Yeah this will work for changing white to a color, but for more complex color transformations you'll have to experiment with the other filter elements or blend modes.

Comment: `Multiply` or `darken` turns white to a color, `screen` or `lighten` turns black to a color. Looks like doing both at once is beyond `feBlend` but may be doable with `feComposite`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just pick the nodes and change their properties.

[In example](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/EksCI):

```
document.querySelector('#g2161').setAttribute('style','fill:blue');
```

- Original svg http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get fill styles to apply to images.

Comment: Oh sorry, maybe you can manipulate pixels then http://beej.us/blog/data/html5s-canvas-2-pixel/