# svg feComponentTransfer linear function

Tags: svg, svg-filters

The SVG `feComponentTransfer` linear function isn't working as I expect it to. A slope of -1 and intercept of 1 applied to a grayscale image should invert the image: black -> white, white-> black, 25% gray -> 75% gray, 50% gray unchanged, and so on.

My expectation is based on http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#feComponentTransferElement, which says "C' = slope * C + intercept" where "C is the initial component (e.g., ‘feFuncR’), C' is the remapped component; both in the closed interval [0,1].".

The following filter

```
<filter id="linear">
  <feComponentTransfer>
    <feFuncR type="linear" slope="-1" intercept="1" />
    <feFuncG type="linear" slope="-1" intercept="1" />
    <feFuncB type="linear" slope="-1" intercept="1" />
  </feComponentTransfer>
</filter>
```

maps black to white and white to black, but intermediate values are off, e.g. 50% gray maps to 90% gray and 75% gray maps to 98% gray. See http://jsfiddle.net/Rpjs2/ for a simple example. I get the same results in Firefox and Safari.

This is my first attempt at SVG filters, so I suspect I'm misunderstanding the specs. Can someone correct me?

Comment: Check out [this example](http://src.chromium.org/chrome/branches/WebKit/195/LayoutTests/svg/custom/feComponentTransfer-Linear.svg) from the WebKit source code. Using a similar filter does "invert" the gradient (look at the filter definitions, as the text describing them is incorrect) but not perfectly. It seems to be shifted to the left a bit.

Comment: It's shifted to the left quite a lot actually, nowhere near what one would get by applying -1*c+1. My first thought is that this is a bug, in that it does not match the w3 spec, but it is odd that Safari and Firefox implemented it in the same (apparently wrong) way. I've filed bug reports to Mozilla and WebKit and will report back if they consider it a bug.

Comment: You inspired me to doc feComponentTransfer in the webplatform docs. Let me know what you think: http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/svg/elements/feComponentTransfer

Comment: @MichaelMullany That looks very useful. Wish I had seen it when I was working on this last week! (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043585/colorizing-grayscale-image illustrates what I was trying to do.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filters generally work in the linearRGB colour space. This use case wants sRGB so you just need to set [color-interpolation-filters](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#ColorInterpolationFiltersProperty)="sRGB" on the filter element

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that. It works in Firefox and Chrome, but Safari ignores it the setting. (Annoying that Safari's release build uses older versions of WebKit than Chrome. There are a lot of SVG bugs in Safari that were fixed months ago in WebKit and do not appear in Chrome.)

Answer (score 0):

You can **mostly** correct for this using another component transfer after your original.

```
  <feComponentTransfer>
    <feFuncR type="gamma" offset="0" amplitude="1" exponent="4.84"/>
    <feFuncG type="gamma" offset="0" amplitude="1" exponent="4.84"/>
    <feFuncB type="gamma" offset="0" amplitude="1" exponent="4.84"/>
  </feComponentTransfer>
```

This will spread out the color range more appropriately using a "double" gamma correction of `2.2 ^ 2 = 4.84`.